# Which types are allowed as a argument when we define generics with super keyword?

Tags: java, generics, functional-interface

I don't understand why I'm getting compilation error in the first line of this function:

```
public void method(Function<? super String, Integer> mapper) {
        mapper.apply(new Object()); // compiler error
        mapper.apply(new String()); // no errors
}
```

I would expect that I can pass Object instance to apply method because for Function interface I defined generic argument as a `? super String` so from my understanding argument can be String and all super classes of String. (So only Object in this example).
But it looks like only String works. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because the declaration `Function<? super String, Integer> mapper` means that `mapper` can either be a `Function<Object, Integer>` or a `Function<String, Integer>`.  In other words, either one of those two things could be passed to this method.

But if `mapper` is a `Function<String, Integer>`, then `mapper.apply(new Object())` makes no sense, because its argument has to be a `String`.  So this is a compile error.

On the other hand, `mapper.apply(new String())` makes sense regardless of whether `mapper` is a `Function<Object, Integer>` or a `Function<String, Integer>`, so the compiler allows this.